# Bash - saving string to separate variable after custom delimiter

Tags: string, bash, parsing, scripting

I'm fairly new to Bash so please forgive me, but I'm building a Bash script that can accept a user input command that can have a lot of switches. I need to write a function that pulls specific data from that user provided command.

I can't seem to find a way to pull each word after "-mode" and push it into an array or list of some sort.

Here is an example of what the user input command might look like:

```
/home/custom/function/that/accepts/a/billion/switches  random_info random_info2 -worker vendor_schmo  -switch_one  -anotherOne  -more_switches  -optionTwo        -mode FOO -mode BAR -mode BAZ -mode BAG -mode DAT -mode RAR
```

I've tried fiddling with awk -F "-mode" '{ print $1 }' and that didn't work. Any advice would be much appreciated!!

Here is the snippet from the script that pulls this info:

```
manualRunMain(){
  local command
  manualRunHeaderPrint
  echo
  echo
  echo
  echo
  lineBreakPrint
  read -p "Enter your command here: " command
  sleep .25
  manualRun "$command"
}

manualRun(){
  manualRunHeaderPrint
  jobRunSubHeaderPrint
  pullModeNames "$1"
}

pullModeNames(){

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, could you please add sample expected output in code tags too?

Comment: I don't think I need anything output, I just need to push each word after each "-mode" into an array. I think that would be enough and I could take it from there.

Comment: In general, you should consider following the practices given in [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) for your given purpose. The list of arguments your command is given is **not** passed as a string -- rather, it's passed as an array of strings -- and treating it as if a string means you adopt a bunch of bugs (for instance, you lose the ability to distinguish between `-foo "bar baz"` and `-foo bar baz`).

Comment: (and if you have a string and need to split it into a list of strings in a way that's comparable to what the shell would do, such that that array can then be parsed through using standard tools, that's a fairly involved question in its own right, with an answer that's *much* more complicated than `array=( $string )`; that said, it *is* a question with accepted, canonical answers already present in our knowledge base).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RS` variable in awk to tell to split data into separate records when it get `-mode`:

```
s='/home/custom/function/that/accepts/a/billion/switches  random_info random_info2 -worker vendor_schmo  -switch_one  -anotherOne  -more_switches  -optionTwo        -mode FOO -mode BAR -mode BAZ -mode BAG -mode DAT -mode RAR'

printf '%s' "$s" | awk -v RS="-mode[[:space:]]*" 'NR>1'
FOO
BAR
BAZ
BAG
DAT
RAR
```

To populate an array:

```
mapfile -t arr < <(printf '%s' "$s" | awk -v RS="-mode[[:space:]]*" 'NR>1')

# examine array content
declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="FOO" [1]="BAR" [2]="BAZ" [3]="BAG" [4]="DAT" [5]="RAR")
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. I'd upvote you but I don't have reputation to do it yet :)

Comment: Notice that the command to populate an array is subject to word splitting and glob expansion, so if you have an argument `-mode 'has space'`, it will break. Instead, you could use `mapfile`: `mapfile -t arr < <(awk -v RS="-mode" 'NR>1{ print $1 }' <<< "$s")`

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Very good point, however if there is any whitespace then even `print $1` will print only first part.

Comment: Since you're using `RS`, can't you print `$0` in the first place? Might have to adjust `RS` to swallow whitespace. Something like `RS="-mode *"`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I was actually thinking of same thing (edited now).

Comment: BTW, I agree that this is the best answer to the question asked in the title, but the intended use case given in the question text (command-line parsing) gives me qualms about this answer's fitness to purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with basically the same answer as @anubhava but with GNU grep instead of awk:

```
$ cmd="... -more_switches  -mode FOO BAR -mode BAZ -mode BAG -mode CAT DAT HAT -mode RAR"
$ mapfile -t modes < <(grep -oP -- '-mode \K.+?(?= -mode|$)' <<<"$cmd")
$ printf "%s\n" "${modes[@]}"
FOO BAR
BAZ
BAG
CAT DAT HAT
RAR
```